# How to import a python .py file in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, python-3.8

I have a Jupyter Notebook and I would like to use some credentials I have put into a config.py file. This file is in the same folder as the Jupyter Notebook.

I use the line

```
import config
```

The problem is Jupyter replies with this message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config.py'; 'config' is not a package
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you everyone for their answers. I have found a way to solve my need using Dotenv Python Package: https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I have found a way to solve my need using Dotenv Python Package: pypi.org/project/python-dotenv

What needs to be done? Insert the following lines:

```
!pip install python-dotenv

# Credentials file
%load_ext dotenv
%dotenv
import os
```

Then place a hidden file named **.env** where the credentials are places. In my case it looks like this:

```
CLIENT_ID = "XXXX"
CLIENT_SECRET = "YYYY"
```

Then, in your notebook file, whenever you need to load the credentials use:

```
CLIENT_ID = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID")
CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")
```

And you are good to go!

Credit to http://veekaybee.github.io/2020/02/25/secrets/ for the solution

Answer (score 3):

You may need to try

```
from config import <the_function_you_want_to_use>
```

This should work with global variables too depending on how you stored your credentials in config. If you are importing the module from a different folder you could make the folder into a package by creating an empty .py file in the folder called:

```
__init__.py
```

Then storing a copy of the .py file you want to use as a module there and calling it.
I'm new at this so I hope this helps.

Comment: Why would `from config import` work if the normal `import` doesn't work?

Comment: What I gathered from your explanation was that your project was having an issue importing what you wanted, so using the explicit call might help. What exactly are you trying to import?

Answer (score -1):

The `import` statement is used to bring in external libraries to use in your program. I think you may be looking to read the file, so provided it is in the same folder path as your notebook you can use this:

```
file = open("config.py", "r")
```

You can then set the contents in the file to a variable and print it out for example using:

```
fileContents = file.read()
print(fileContents)
```

You may wish to use a csv format and add some sort of encryption if this is a stored password for example.

Comment: This is not necessarily true. `import` is just as often used to import custom modules and not just external libraries.